# Comparison of Red/Black Tree to Java ArrayList, what are advantages of each?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

I was looking over some of the general [Big-O Algorithm Complexities](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) for different data structures, and wondered what Java's `ArrayList` would be considered.

Since I tend to default to an `ArrayList` in my Java code when I need a `List` (*unless I know I need some additional functionality*), I was wondering what advantages there would be if I used an implementation (*assume well-implemented*) of a Red-Black Tree instead.

Since `ArrayList` is backed by an `Array`, I would assume that it would be considered either an `Array` or a `Singly-Linked List` according to the linked website. If that is true, it would appear that a Red-Black Tree implementation might a better "default" data structure to use.

What would be the advantages/disadvantages of using a Red-Black Tree instead of the ArrayList? (*and minor accompanying question, what would `ArrayList` be considered in the [Algorithm Complexities](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) website?*)

Comment: One's a tree, the other is a list. Nuff' said.

Comment: Is the data desired to be always sorted? Can it be sorted? Accessed by index? Do you want to have duplicates? Nulls? --- they are very different structures for very different problems.

Comment: OK, a bit more details: They have different uses and pros/cons, it's very rare that they are even comparable. The tree is for `Comparable` data only, good for many random modifications and the occasional lookup *by value*. The list is for any ordered, but not necessarily `Comparable` data, good for sequential or random access *by position* or value if comparable and binary-search, as well as appending or removing values to the end. In that table an `ArrayList` would fit the `Array` category, although "search" is not always applicable. Also, `ArrayList` is more performant due to cache locality.

Comment: recommended reading: **[What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)**

Answer (score 1):

Since this is about Java, it is worth separating the interfaces from the implementations in its Collections framework.

ArrayList and LinkedList are both types of List. A List is an ordered collection referenced by arbitrary index (i.e. the index is not a property of the data being stored). ArrayList is backed by an array, which is sequence, random-access storage. These are really good when you need to access random elements and are not inserting in the middle: ArrayList supports this operation, but it is potentially slow.

TreeMap and TreeSet are types of Map and Set (and the Sets delegate to the Trees, so the differences in practice are nil). These objects are referenced by some property (key) which is an arbitrary object: for a map it can be anything you want (typically a string), for a set it is the element itself. These are ordered collections, meaning elements in the tree are ordered either by the natural ordering of the elements or by some other criteria (this is what the Comparator interface is used for).

So the differences are:

- Access: by index for the list, by key or element for the tree.
- Mutation: both are ordered, but a list is in any arbitrary order while the tree resorts itself as you insert elements.

You would use a list when you don't need to access elements by a key, you just need a bunch of objects *or* you need them in a particular order that is not their natural ordering. You would use a tree (or hashtable) when you want a key/value store similar to retrieving records from a database by primary key.

Comment: The random access nature is hinted at with the [RandomAccess](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) marker interface.

Comment: @MichaelT yep, and I have actually written performance-critical code that checks for that interface (as opposed to ArrayList).

Comment: If the key of the Tree was the index, and the Tree supported a simple `add(Object)` method which inserted according to the last index (*so at the end*), would they be more comparable? Would there be any reason to do that?

Comment: @DoubleDouble yes, they would be comparable in terms of their interface, but the implementation would still be different. Adding on to the end of the tree is O(log n) while O(1) for the array list. I have done this before when I needed a sparse list, where there might be gaps.